# Error downloading all files of a directory using Laravel s3 with ZipArchive

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I am trying to download all files of a directory from digital ocean space that works like amazon s3. I  have written the code below for the purpose:

```
            $zip = new \ZipArchive();
            $fileName = $exam->id . '.zip';
            $files = Storage::disk('do')->files('answers/' . $id);
            if ($zip->open(($fileName), \ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
                foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
                    $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
                    $zip->addFile(Storage::disk('do')->url($value), $relativeNameInZipFile);
                }
                $zip->close();
            }
            return \response()->download(public_path($fileName));
```

It gives me an error saying:

```
The file "H:\development\code\aminulsacademy.com\public\5.zip" does not exist
```

The `$files` variable gives me the following data:

```
$files = Storage::disk('do')->files('answers/' . $id);
```

Output:

```
["answers/5/1_4.pdf", "answers/5/1_4_reviewed.pdf", "answers/5/3_4.pdf","answers/5/3_4_reviewed.pdf"]
```

Can anyone help me?